# Health Kit - Update samples

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I couldn't find explicit method to update samples in *HKHealthStore* so what I'm doing is deleting a sample and adding updated one.

```
public func deleteGlucoseMeasurement(measurement: Measurement, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    Health.shared.delete(measurement.sample, withCompletion: completion)
}

public func updateGlucoseMeasurement(unit: Health.Unit, measurement: Measurement, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    deleteGlucoseMeasurement(measurement: measurement) { (success, error) in
        if(error != nil || !success) {
            completion(success, error)
            return
        }
        self.saveGlucose(unit: unit, glucose: measurement.glucose, description: measurement.description, date: measurement.date, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

However I'm receiving
*error: Optional("Failed to find some objects for deletion.")*, for sample which is not added by my app.

So is there a way to update such sample, or at least check if such sample is editable?

Comment: What is `Health`? Is that your custom class?

Comment: Just a helper of hkhealthstore

Comment: Can you share the delete method of this helper?

Comment: That's a HKHealthStore method...